# Bootstrap4 Carousel Controls Inactive

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Having followed the official Bootstrap tutorial, I'm trying to run a carousel with three images. For the purposes of asking I changed the links, but the issue remains the same. While the arrows appear to respond in one way or another, the image never changes. I tried using jQuery to call on that problem specifically to no avail. I need to be able to rotate through at least three images for this to be successful. I've been using Google Chrome as my browser.

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.1.0/lux/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>My Art</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Navbar Start -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Daniye S. Bartell</a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Art</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Projects</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Navbar End -->
    <!-- Start Main Container -->
  <div id="main-art" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="text-center art-paragraph">
      <h1>Glitch Art</h1>
      <p>Glitch art has been a passion of mine for about two years now. It never gets old learning new ways to break computer logic and reasoning. It goes without saying that I've broken many a file, but I've never considered those failures. I've thought of them as methods of discovery for new ways to create beautiful new images. I've turned some pictures into sound, taken the hex code and inserted song lyrics, reformatted them in text editors and much, much more. Currently I'm working on a web app that makes it easy for the average person to make their own glitch art! Found below are some of my favorite pieces of work. Generally the style is characterized by misplaced RGB patterns, high saturation and sliding pixels- but the magic of it all is that it's so unpredictable what you'll get! I hope you enjoy looking at my work as much as I did making it.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Carousel Code Start -->
    <div class="carousel slide" id="glitchCarousel" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <!-- Carousel Items -->
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="https://topbackgroundwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/space-1080p-wallpaper-space-cataclysm-planet-art-explosion-asteroids-comets-fragments-98315-1920x1080.jpg" alt="First Pic" class="d-block w-100"/>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/zIRiIpc.jpg" alt="Second Pic" class="d-block w-100"/>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/OlMlERn.jpg" alt="Third Pic" class="d-block w-100"/>
        </div>
        <!-- Carousel Item End -->
      </div>
      <a href="#glitchCarousel" class="carousel-control-prev" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#glitchCarousel" class="carousel-control-next" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Carousel Code End -->
  </div>
  <!-- End Main Container -->
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#selfie
{
  border-radius: 20%;
  padding: 30px;
}

.info
{
  color: #000;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#main-art
{

}
.art-paragraph
{
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: #000;
  margin:auto;
  max-width: 50%;
}

#glitchCarousel
{
  max-width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000;
  border-width: 12px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Your carousel works fine; did you remember to include Bootstrap's required JavaScript assets?

Answer (score 0):

Jquery and popper.js are dependencies of bootstrap! For components to work you must add jQuery. So please add jQuery!

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```